# TTL mongo for specific entry array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I read that [mongodb has TTL](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) (Time to live) indexes that can be activated for document.

But does it work if document structure is as follows?

```
username: 'user x',
activity: [
  {type:a, desc:1, timestamp:timestamp},
  {type:b, desc:2, timestamp:timestamp},
  {type:b, desc:3, timestamp:timestamp},
  etc.
]
```

Is there possibility to set TTL based on `timestamp+7days` of each array item so that only those expires but recent ones are kept?

Answer (score 4):

Read the documentation carefully, The TTL index can be applied to an array but it will delete the whole document when expired not just the element inside the array.

However, you could split the array out into many documents?

Comment: Thanks, so there is no way to use TTL then... perhaps have to setup cron task to remove entries manually, hmm...

Comment: You could break out the area so each item is a document, then just join it back up when you query

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no way to delete specific elements from an array using a TTL index. There's a [feature request](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10286) for this, but it seems like at the moment the best way to do this is to create a separate collection that links to the `_id` of your documents.

So in your case, instead of adding an `activity` array to all your users, you create an extra `activities` collections which contains documents like this:

```
{type:a, desc:1, timestamp:timestamp, userId:ObjectId("611636e533f29e4bd6683b05")}
{type:b, desc:2, timestamp:timestamp, userId:ObjectId("611636e533f29e4bd6683b05")}
{type:b, desc:3, timestamp:timestamp, userId:ObjectId("611636e533f29e4bd6683b05")}
```